# Overriding default `autocomplete` behavior of browsers

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, browser

Users does like `autocomplete` on fields, and its indeed beneficial to have it in your application. Also, there are many ways to implement custom `autocomplete` (ajaxified, dumber, intelligent, etc.) dropdowns, if you know even basic Javascripts.

Recipes are more or less the same.

- disable browser's autocomplete
- event-capturing
- querying matched data
- show in a relatively positioned and custom-styled ul/div

My question: Is there a way to use browser's own `autocomplete` feature to show custom data, to provide a more native experience?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The browser's autocomplete is client-side only, and can't be accessed from js.
My bet would be that this is to prevent data-mining.